# How to check if value is in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataFrame:

[image: df]

How can I filter column G, to exclude rows that the value is in column C? The result should look like this:

[image: df_updated]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try df.loc with isin + ~ which negates it

```
df.loc[~df['G'].isin(df['C'].unique())]
```

Comment: Worked!! I was struggling with another problem. I've tried df.loc before but my 'C' column was a different type (int64) and I had to convert back to Object. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a mask in this case:

```
df_filtered = df[~df['G'].isin(df['C'])]
```